# Set caret position in JFace TextViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I want to create some Macro abilities in a TextViewer. So I attached a TextListener. In its textChanged-Method I check for a Macro-Hotkey. Whenever it encounters this hotkey, the TextListener analyzes the word just before and then replaces it against the macro contents (via TextViewer#getDocument().replace()). This works.

Now just after replacing the macro name with its contents, I would like to place the caret to a position just after the macro contents. This doesn't work. I tried to call TextViewer.setSelectedRange(offset,0) and I tried ((StyledText)TextViewer.getControl()).setCaretOffset(offset). But the Caret remains always at the position where the hotkey was entered.

Any ideas?